# Yii ajax validation: как прослушивать изменения?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

При добавлении и удалении сообщений об ошибках хочу выполнять изменения размеров всей формы.(через javascript)

Если использую костыли (смотрю на появление этих самых сообщений(дивов) и тп.), то получается рассинхрон, добавление задержки (`setTimeout`) не особо помогает.

Засунул свою функцию пока что в сам `/framework/web/js/source/jquery.yiiactiveform.js` где исполняется код по появлению этих сообщений (3 места) - все идеально.

```
<?php $activeform = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
        ),
));
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, элементы Вашего кода. Хотя бы то, как Вы формируете эти ошибки, почему они отображаются, и какой механизм они используют при своем появлении.

Comment: Это самые стандартные сообщения об ошибках при валидации формы. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#error-detail <?php echo $form->error($model,'attribute'); ?>

Comment: покажите вашу форму используется или нет ajax какие настройки для нее? покажите код который вы вставили в  jquery.yiiactiveform.js некоторым это даст понять что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Это действительно помогло?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть events типа beforeValidate и т.д.

```
<?php
    $js = <<<JAVASCRIPT
    jQuery('#myform').on("beforeValidate", function(event, messages, deferreds) {
            // тут делай что хочешь
    });
    JAVASCRIPT;
    $this->registerJs($js);
```